# In PyParsing, how to define a setParseAction function to convert a list of strings to a list of integers?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm getting a `ParseResult` which is a list of strings which represent numbers, for example,

```
['160', '240', '320', '480', '640']
```

which I'd like to convert to the corresponding list of integers:

```
[160, 240, 320, 480, 640]
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out the right function to put into the `setParseAction` method to achieve this result. Here is what I've tried so far (in Python 2):

```
In [1]: from pyparsing import *

In [2]: string = "densities: '160' '240' '320' '480' '640'"

In [3]: densities = LineStart() + "densities:" + OneOrMore(QuotedString(quoteChar="'"))("densities").setParseAction(lambda tokens: map(int, tokens))

In [4]: tokens = densities.parseString(string)

In [5]: tokens.asDict()
Out[5]: {'densities': [160]}
```

The parse action seems to only convert the first string to an integer. How can I modify this to achieve the desired list of integers? Or perhaps more generally: what do the `tokens` given to the function in `setParseAction` represent exactly?

**Update**

Following, [Paul McGuire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paul-mcguire)'s comments and answer, I've tried using `.setParseAction(tokenMap(int))`, but the resulting named result `densities` is still only `[160]`:

```
In [1]: from pyparsing import *

In [2]: string = "densities: '160' '240' '320' '480' '640'"

In [3]: densities = LineStart() + "densities:" + OneOrMore(QuotedString(quoteCha
   ...: r="'"))("densities").setParseAction(tokenMap(int))

In [4]: tokens = densities.parseString(string)

In [5]: tokens.asDict()
Out[5]: {'densities': [160]}
```

I've also tried gaining more insight into the process using `traceParseAction`:

```
In [6]: densities = LineStart() + "densities:" + OneOrMore(QuotedString(quoteChar="'"))("densities").setParseAction(traceParseAction(tokenMap(int)))

In [7]: tokens = densities.parseString(string)
>>entering int(line: 'densities: '160' '240' '320' '480' '640'', 11, (['160', '240', '320', '480', '640'], {'densities': [(['160', '240', '320', '480', '640'], {})]}))
<<leaving int (ret: [160, 240, 320, 480, 640])
```

The `ret` shown here is the desired result, but somehow it doesn't appear to be the same as `tokens.asDict()['densities']`?

Comment: Wrap your parse action with the `traceParseAction` decorator to see what goes into and comes back from your parse action.  Since you have used a lambda, do `setParseAction(traceParseAction(lambda ... etc.... ))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `pyparsing_common.convertToInteger` parse action will do the trick, which is implemented using `pyparsing.tokenMap(int)`.

`pyparsing.tokenMap` will generate parse actions that take a function that will operate on a single token, and apply it to all the parsed tokens.  More info on `tokenMap` here: https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html#tokenMap

EDIT:
Seems that `Group`ing is also required to get this to work:

```
densities = (LineStart()
             + "densities:"
             + Group(OneOrMore(QuotedString(quoteChar="'")).setParseAction(tokenMap(int)))("densities")
             )
```

Or, move the parse action inside the `OneOrMore`:

```
densities = (LineStart()
             + "densities:"
             + OneOrMore(QuotedString(quoteChar="'").setParseAction(tokenMap(int)))("densities")
             )
```

Comment: The `tokenMap(int)` parse action seems to yield the same result as the original `lambda tokens: map(int, tokens)`: the named result `densities` is still `[160]` and not `[160, 240, 320, 480, 640]`? (I've also updated the question).